# Classic cross domain ajax with jquery client side PHP server side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

It is about a javascript pixel to follow up who does what in a sales funnel on the web.

I have a javascript script on my customer thrivecart domain (e.g. https://ownspace.thrivecart.com)

I want to make a request to another domain (e.g. https://emails.mycustomer.com) from which the javascript script is from.

Here is the main part of the javacsript code on https://ownspace.thrivecart.com :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("loading pixel");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://emails.mycustomer.com/server_side_script.php',
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                data: {my:ciphered_get_parameters},
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

Here is what I have server side for the moment : (server_side_script.php)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:application/json'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://ownspace.thrivecart.com");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Accept");
// Special data treatment
```

I get this error on the thrivecart page :

```
Failed to load https://emails.mycustomer.com/server_side_script.php: Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

However, I read that "
     `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` : 
Indicates which headers are supported by the response’s url for the purposes of the CORS protocol."

As the header is on in the PHP code, I don't understand why it does not work.

I even tried to set the X-Requested-With header in the response with NGINX conf file, restarting the server.

But, I think I miss a point.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966. In chrome dev tools network inspect the actual OPTIONS request and see what headers actually are included

Comment: Nothing I have not read about before asking and I don't think it is a typo.

Comment: So what do you see when you inspect the actual OPTIONS request response headers in chrome?

Comment: Yes, I see a "Yes, you have CORS!" with the w3 PHP script

Comment: Not clear if that means problem solved or not

Comment: I did not change anything to my code, so, problem not solved. I am going to work on it, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164196/discussion-between-mantisse-and-charlietfl).

Comment: It is a typo in the PHP headers, thanks charlietfl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a typo in

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Accept");
```

Try

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Accept");
```